# Генерация xls

Tags: php, xls

Есть таблица:

`Ид, Имя, Емейл, Дата, Время, Баллы`

Вопрос: как с помощью php сохранить все это в xls и предоставить юзеру для загрузки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Импорт и экспорт данных с помощью PHPExcel](http://blog.kron0s.com/phpexcel) - либа тяжелая конечно, но мощная.
- [PHP, подружим PHP и Excel](http://gv0zdik.livejournal.com/9385.html?thread=101545) - вот описание другой либы.

Answer (score 1):

- Есть для этого библиотека, называется "[Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer)".
- А так же возможно создание без сторонних библиотек, в упрощенном виде, т.е. никаких раскрашиваний ячеек, размеров шрифтов и формул. Просто записываем какие-либо данные в нужные ячейки. [Смотреть тут](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/18726/).

Answer (score 1):

Если без оформлений (подгонка ширины столбцов, жирность, цвет и т.д.), то можно просто выбрать нужные ячейки и выписывать их в любой файл в виде строк или в переменную, которую после выдать юзеру в виде файла. В каждой строке ваши поля разделенные знаком "точка с запятой". Файлу дать расширение `CSV`.
А если нужно с оформлением, то берем сторонние библиотеки для работы с эселем. Я, например, предпочитаю `PHPExcel` (как пример вот простое [описание заполнения файла](http://www.web-junior.net/sozdanie-excel-fajjlov-s-pomoshhyu-phpexcel/)).

Answer (score 0):

Если вас устроит XLSX (для последних версий офиса), то там просто XML, который сгенерировать не проблема. То есть берем готовый .xlsx, смотрим где чего нужно добавить прои добавлении еще одной строчки и генерим...

Answer (score 0):

А хотите простое сохранение в XLS?

Возьми и всю инфу которая тебе нужна запиши в файл в виде HTML таблицы тупо и файлу расширение .xls поставь. будет тебе быстрое счастье :)